# How to use ngCordova facebook plugin?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to develop a facebook-login in my ionic app. I want to use ngCordova Facebook plugin and I've followed the instructions from there but I receive an error: `facebook connect plugin is not defined`.

What should I do? I've followed instructions for Android and my app is ionic based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this detailed article - [OAuth with Ionic and ngCordova](http://blog.ionic.io/oauth-ionic-ngcordova/)

Or add link to the document that you are using and specify a step where you was stopped?

Have you followed this [guide](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/)?

**EDIT:** Ok, I check my source code. I havn't used any SDK depended plugins.
I am using light weight library [OpenFB](https://github.com/adriancmiranda/OpenFB). I followed by steps presented in readme and logged in fb in my ionic app.

**EDIT2:** BTW, I have tried with [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/) wrapper (I added it first version of my answer) same result.

I thought what you missed.. Possible that you don't added link to facebookConnectPlugin.js?

My index.html page:

```
<script src="js/facebookConnectPlugin.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaFacebook) {
    $scope.getLoginStatus = function () {
        $cordovaFacebook.getLoginStatus().then(function (status) {
            $scope.status = status;
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.status = error;
        })
    };
    $scope.login = function () {
        $cordovaFacebook.login(["public_profile"]).then(function (success) {
            $scope.loginInfo = success;
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.error = error;
            alert(error);
        })
    };
    $scope.logout = function () {
        $cordovaFacebook.logout().then(function (success) {
            console.log(success);
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.error = error;
            alert(error);
        })
    };
    $scope.getMe = function () {
        $scope.me = ["refreshing..."];
        $cordovaFacebook.api("me", null).then(function (success) {
            $scope.me = success;
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.error = error;
        })
    };
})
```

View:

```
<button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
<h5>Login info</h5>
<div ng-repeat="info in loginInfo">{{info}}</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="item item-divider">Login Info</div>
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="info in loginInfo">{{info}}</div>
</div>
<button class="button button-block button-dark" ng-click="getLoginStatus()">Check Login Status</button>
<div class="card">
    <div class="item item-divider">Login Status</div>
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="info in status">{{info}}</div>
</div>
<button class="button button-block button-energized" ng-click="getMe()">API - get Me</button>
<h5>Api Me info</h5>
<div class="card">
    <div class="item item-divider">Api Me info</div>
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="info in me">{{info}}</div>
</div>
<button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="logout()">Logout</button>
```

If it doesn't help - I will put my source on github tomorrow.

Comment: I've followed..but i need to connect to native fb application to do login

Comment: I can say i'm close to resolve this...now i receive an error from facebook :.To use this url you must add a valid native platform in your App's settings

Comment: I will try at home in the evening. I did it before for PhoneGap but used other approaches

Comment: Ok..i wait for your answer...i try to resolve this error ..i will post if i succed

Comment: I've succed...I must do some settings at facebook developers! anyway..your answer is good!

Comment: Unknown provider: $cordovaFacebookProvider <- $cordovaFacebook